# How to inject component into a div selector in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-frontend

I would like to know if there is anyway for me to inject a component into a div selector () using either a class or id.
I know how to inject a component into another component but don't know how to go about it with injecting it into a div selector.

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: I want to inject a component inside a div element

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewContainerRef` to inject components or templates into containers, which can be selected using `@ViewChild` by either the tag or an ID.

This blog post goes over a couple different ways to inject a template into a view container.

**Understanding ViewContainerRef in Angular 2**: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-understanding-viewcontainerref-acc183f3b682

There's another post that details creating dynamic components that are injected into a parent component, which can also be done using an element's ID.

**Dynamically Creating Components With Angular**:
https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d